# How to use webpack and Datatable on Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, datatable

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and datatable  I have a index.js that load all my components, and datatable/index.js with this content

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'datatables.net';

export default (function () {
 $('#dataTable').DataTable();
}())
```

when I run `npm run watch`, no error on the CLI, but I get this error on the chrome console : `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_jquery__(...).DataTable`

Here is the full project : https://github.com/kossa/laradminator and https://github.com/kossa/laradminator/blob/master/resources/js/datatable/index.js

Comment: try cleaning your cache. php artisan cache:clear

Comment: Show the contents of your `webpack.mix.js`